# Capture high quality picture and record video without delay using NextLevel

Tags: ios

Using the [NextLevel](https://github.com/NextLevel/NextLevel) library for image capture in iOS, I want to be able to take a high quality photo, or record a video at any given moment, but I can only take a photo if `NextLevel.shared.captureMode == .photo` and I can only take a video if `NextLevel.shared.captureMode == .video`. There's a delay and a callback after changing the setting.

So, the only thing I can think of is to change the mode whenever I want to capture a photo or capture a video. Then in the callback I would know whether I wanted to capture a video or take a photo based on the mode that it switched to, or some flag that I set.

Comment: This maybe fundamentally a performance issue, the hardware probably cannot support, fast enough what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: That makes sense hopefully that is not the case, I will still wait for a response from the developer who wrote this library. He said to tag questions here with [nextlevel] but I was unable to tag that because I cannot create a new tag on stack overflow.